# Parse.com - How do I load all images in PFQueryTableViewController at once?

Tags: iphone, ios, parse-platform

In [Parse's AnyPic sample app](https://www.parse.com/tutorials/anypic), the photos from each table cell only get downloaded if you scroll to them and wait a couple seconds.

Is there any way to make the app download all the images in a PFQueryTableViewController at once, so the user doesn't have to pause on each photo to get it to load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [cell.imageView loadInBackground] in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:object: to load the images anyway without waiting for the table to stop.

If you want to download all images without needing to scroll the table, you can do so in objectDidLoad. Just iterate through self.objects and obtain the PFFile, then call getDataInBackground for each file in order to initiate the download. They will be saved to disk and should load instantly if they are available by the time you scroll the table.

Comment: Is there any downside to using the second option?

Comment: Also, I noticed that AnyPic does call `loadInBackground` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. What's preventing AnyPic from loading the images until the user stops scrolling? Thanks for your patience!

Comment: It's only calling loadInBackground if the data is already available locally, in order to display the image immediately. As opposed to waiting for scrolling to stop before creating a network request.